# Does the Socrata SODA API provide a last modified date for a table?

Tags: soda, socrata

On the web portal, every dataset has a last modified date, however I don't see anything in the API docs (or the response for that matter). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another place you can find this information is the the /data.json API available on all Socrata-powered sites. For example, http://data.seattle.gov/data.json

This lists every dataset on the site along with metadata such as last modified date.

Answer (score 2):

Found it in the header! Surprise, it's "Last-Modified"

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 15 May 2014 17:15:51 GMT
Etag: "147733f4e69d7a2e5df8690c3dbc9f63"
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 May 2014 18:46:08 UTC
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Socrata-Region: production
X-Soda2-Fields: ["region",":updated_at","source","location","magnitude","number_of_stations",":id","datetime",":created_at","earthquake_id","depth","version"]
X-Soda2-Legacy-Types: true
X-Soda2-Types: ["text","meta_data","text","location","number","number","meta_data","calendar_date","meta_data","text","number","text"]
X-Soda2-Warning: X-SODA2-Fields, X-SODA2-Types, and X-SODA2-Legacy-Types are deprecated
```

Comment: Exactly! We stuff lots of great info into the headers. We'll be adding more in the future as well.

Comment: hey @chrismetcalf, a lot of the headers seem to be deprecated but no mention of replacements (e.g. field types). Thoughts?