# Does the Socrata SODA API support getting a list of dates on which the dataset was modified?

Tags: socrata, soda

Does the Socrata SODA API support a method to query out all the dates a dataset has been updated? Basically a changelog for the dataset that has an object for every modification/update to a dataset.

There is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684811/does-the-socrata-soda-api-provide-a-last-modified-date-for-a-table) that asks for the last modified date (you can get it through the "/data.json API available on all Socrata-powered sites".

There is also a method to get the modified dates of individual rows using [System Fields](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/system-fields.html) and the `:update_at` field. But this is incomplete, a data provider might update every row each time. This means there is no guarantee that we are really getting back a history of modifications, just the top layer of modification on each row.

I'm looking for the complete list of modification dates, at least. We are trying to get a sense of activity on datasets and we need to know how often they are being updated.

Comment: It looks like the /api/view/xxxx-xxxx/rows.json endpoint doesn't have this either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823583/is-there-a-socrata-api-for-reading-a-datasets-metadata. It also only has the most recent updated date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Max, we don't offer what you're looking for. We've got the last time the dataset and metadata were modified, but not a changelog of every single time that there was a change.

A surprisingly large number of datasets change very frequently, as often as every 5 minutes.

Comment: Bummer, but that makes sense.  From our perspective it would be nice to see how often they update even if it's at a less granular level (day, week, month instead of minute). Thanks for the help!